# Google Earth for iOS / iPad, iPhone support for LookAt and Camera tags missing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, kml, google-earth

I've developed an app that pulls spatial data from an internal database, and generates a KML file.  It consists of some styles, a document-level LookAt tag (for initial positioning), and a couple hundred placemarks with some custom CDATA in the baloons.  When I import this into the PC application, it works perfectly, initially zooming to the correct position and altitude.  When I load the same value using the Apple Google Earth app, it seems to ignore the LookAt tag, positioning itself in the middle of the placemarks at 1500ft.  Below is the actual LookAt tag with xxx substituted for the valid latitude and longitude values.

```
    <LookAt id="LastItem">
       <longitude>xxx</longitude>
       <latitude>xxx</latitude>
       <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
       <altitude>5000</altitude>
       <heading>0</heading>
       <tilt>60</tilt>           
       <range>25000</range>
    </LookAt>
```

Is this a feature that is not supported in the Apple version of the app?  I've tried using Camera tags with the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

The original Google Earth app for iOS devices DID support a document level `<LookAt>` or `<Camera>` - however at some point it stop doing so :( Instead it now defaults to a view situated 500m (or maybe ft) directly above and looking down at the center point of all the `<Placemarks>` in the first .kml loaded